# How to send push notification using FCM only to offline devices using topics?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a native android and ios app.  I need to send a push notification using FCM to offline users or when the app is in the background or closed to a single device or thru topics. In particular, I want to send a push notification to a topic and FCM should send a notification to only who is offline. It should ignore the online users. Is this possible and anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 3):

I'd highly recommend against trying this approach, as it's likely to be complex and error prone. For example, it's very easy to end up with a race condition where the client doesn't receive a FCM message just after closing the app, or where it still receives the FCM messages just as it is being closed.

Most apps that I know off simply send FCM messages all the time, no matter whether the user is actively using the app or not. The client then decides what to do with the FCM message based on whether the app is active or not.

In fact, this is precisely how [notification messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications) are handled automatically already:

1. if the user is not actively using the app, the notification is displayed in the system tray.
2. if the user is actively using the app, the message is deliver to the application code.

Comment: Thank you Frank for the answer. But isn't it lots of traffic to the app when they are online and sending notifications that are meant to be offline notifications?

Comment: If you're already sending the data through one channel, sending a tickle (a mostly empty notification message for that data) through FCM typically doesn't add that much. But it does of course depend on your use-case.